# How can i tell if the mac show scroll bars setting is always on

Tags: javascript, css, macos

Mac OS provides a setting under general where you can set show scroll bars to always on. When i do this i have a problem with an extra scrollbar i'd like to mitagate by adding some margin. But this would cause a gap if this setting is off and scrollbars are hidden.

On chrome i am able to tell if the scroll bar is on with this:

```
this.bodyWrapperRight[0].offsetHeight - this.tableRight[0].offsetHeight > 0
```

In this case i compare the container width that has the overflow: scroll to the inner element's width.

But this does not seem to work on Firefox or Safari on Mac. Im looking for some way to tell if the scrollbar is set to always visible?

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution based on this http://jsfiddle.net/UU9kg/17/ code to get the scroll bar width:.

```
/**
 * Gets the OS scollbar width in pixels.
 * @returns {number} The width as a number in pixels.
 */
utils.getScrollbarWidth = function () {
  const outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  outer.style.width = '100px';
  document.body.appendChild(outer);

  const widthNoScroll = outer.offsetWidth;
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';

  const inner = document.createElement('div');
  inner.style.width = '100%';
  outer.appendChild(inner);

  const widthWithScroll = inner.offsetWidth;
  outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

  return widthNoScroll - widthWithScroll;
};
```

This works on mac, safari, chrome and firefox. If you run the fiddle page and set the mac scrollbar option it will now always return 15 if the scroll bar is always visible or 0 if it is auto hiding.